# GCP Cloud Function not mounting latest secret from Secret Manager

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, serverless, google-secret-manager

My Cloud Function is referencing an older version of a secret that is mounted, despite using the `:latest` suffix

I have a Cloud Function deployed that mounts a secret when I deploy, explicitly referencing the latest version of the secret:

```
--set-secrets=DATABASE_URL=projects/MY_PROJECT/secrets/DATABASE_URL:latest
```

I see this is set up correctly in my Cloud Function console but when running the function it is referencing a past version of the secret. I am logging the secret to test with `process.env.DATABASE_URL` (it is a Node runtime).

If I redeploy the function this is fixed. I'm confused because [the docs](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/configuring/secrets) specify that mounting the secrets and adding the `:latest` suffix will use the most recent version when the function runs.

Comment: The secret is resolved at instance startup. Review the logs to see if a new instance has been started (a cold start), otherwise, the pervious value will persist. To make the secret dynamic, mount the secret as a volume. The secret will be read on each file read.

Comment: That's the answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The secret is resolved when this instance of the Cloud Function starts. If the function stays active without going to sleep it will keep the old version of the secret mounted asn an environment variable. If you mount the secret as a volume and read the file it will automatically update.

Credit: John Hanley's comment

Comment: That worked! I mistakenly though that specify the Secret Manager path would mount it, not realizing there was a slight nuance there :)

Comment: It's because in Linux environment variables don't change after the process starts. And Google Cloud Functions run as a linux program on Kubernetes via KNative. The process is shut down if it is not called often enough, but if it is called often it stays alive and stays using the old value.